# Excel Application Crash due to Macro

Tags: vba, excel

During launching my macro the Excel application is crashed. If I test the macro with an integer the program runs properly (partnumber = 123). If I check with a string the application is crashed. Thus, no error code is visible for me. I assume that there is a type mismatch (but I set Variant for partnumber)

```
Sub SbIsInCOPexport()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim partnumber As Variant
i = 1
found = False

partnumber = ActiveCell.Value
Windows("COPexport.xlsx").Activate
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Do While i < lastRow + 1
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = partnumber Then
        found = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

If found = True Then
    Cells(i, 6).Select
    MsgBox ("Searched part number: " & Str(partnumber) & vbNewLine & "Found part number: " _
    & ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & "Address: " & Cells(i, 6).Address & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Test Order: " & _
    Cells(i, 2).Value)
    Windows("COPexport.xlsx").Activate
Else
    MsgBox "Part number is not found in the COP samples!"
    Windows("COPexport.xlsx").Activate
End If
End Sub
```

What can be the root cause?

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in this but *why* aren't you using the `Range.Find` method instead of brute force iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious issues, but consider using the `.Find` method of range object, like so:

```
Sub SbIsInCOPexport()
    Dim partnumber as Variant
    Dim rng as Range

    Windows("COPexport.xlsx").Activate
    partnumber = ActiveCell.Value
    Set rng = Columns(6).Find(partnumber)  '## Search in column 6 for partnumber

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Part number is not found in the COP samples!"
        Windows("COPexport.xlsx").Activate
    Else
        With rng
            MsgBox ("Searched part number: " & Str(partnumber) & vbNewLine &  _
                    "Found part number: " & .Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Address: " & .Address & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Test Order: " & .Offset(0,-4).Value)  '## Get the value from column 2
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```